# Is there any way to count the number of android patterns without using brute force?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I am trying to count the number of android patterns, i.e. simple paths, without using brute force. 
The android pattern is a 3x3 graph:

```
 1  2  3
 4  5  6
 7  8  9
```

• The possible length for a pattern is from 4 to 9 vertices.

• Two vertices which are separated by a vertex not yet used are not connected directly (in the graph schematized above, an example could be 1 and 7, that are separated by 4, so we cannot go directly from 1 to 7, we have to go from 1 to 4 and then from 4 to 7).

• The pattern can only use a vertex a single time, however, if a vertex has been already used, the pattern can pass through it (e.g. the pattern 4-5-6-2-8 is valid).

• Also, note that chess-horse-type moves are valid (e.g. 1-8-3).

If you have an answer for the part of counting the simple paths without the "conditional edges" (e.g. {1, 3}, when 2 has already been used) I would also appreciate it.

Comment: So basically, it's permutations of $4$ to $9$ nunbers chosen from a set of $9$ without repeats, but then eliminating an awkward subset of them.

Comment: That could be a possible handle of the problem. I have tried it and it gives some good results for length < 4. The problem is that when handling higher lengths, the number of types of invalid cases increases greatly, and the number of exceptions in those types also does.